# passing array as paramter in URL using jquery/javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, struts2

I am making the url(for viewing specific customer) in my CustomerList.jsp as below where `customer_message` is an request attribute which is an array. 
when I inspect `customer_message` in CustomerList i see it array containing two Float values

```
var custURL="<s:url namespace="/customer action="view-customer" method="viewCustomer"/>?customer_message=<s:property value="#request['customer_message']"/>";
```

But when I get the request in view-customer action and I do `request.getParameter("customer_message")`, I see it containing only one value.

Am I doing some mistake in passing `customer_message` as array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Struts2 use `<s:param>` tag inside `<s:url>` tag to add parameters.

```
<s:url namespace="/customer" action="view-customer" method="viewCustomer">
  <s:param name="customer_message" value="#request['customer_message']"/>
</s:url>
```

From the [`<s:url>`](http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/url.html) tag documentation:

> You can use the `<param>` tag inside the body to provide additional request parameters. If the value of a param is an Array or an Iterable all the values will be added to the URL.

Comment: Thanks Aleks but how will i iterate over the array  at receiving side is it like this <s:iterator var="message" value="#parameters['customer_message']" >
  <s:property value="#message"/>
</s:iterator>